# How to allow access to sensitive data only from ressource server ? [OAuth OpenID]

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

A client receive an valid access_token, I would like to know if i can do it with OAuth2/OpenID:

- I don't want "client" to access user sensitive information like "contract_ID" for example.
- Only my ressource server could access to this sensitive information to make some operations.

Many examples on internet show that /userinfo request is done by the "client" to access some user informations.
So how to allow access to /userinfo only from ressourceserver ? 
The ressourceserver has an "access token" in input. How to use this access_token to access sensitive information without allow "client" to acces this information ?

I did two schema to explained:

- [My fear, I don't want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIUTl.png)
- [I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgBq9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Userinfo endpoint` is a service provided by your Identity provider (IdP). It's a part of OAuth spec - http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo. It depends on IdP configuration, what is exposed in userinfo response.

So, don't expose `contract_ID` in userinfo endpoint, but create some API method `getcontractid`, which will be authenticated/authorized API method and it will retrieve contract ID from your DB.